# Should name lookup "in the class of the object expression" find members of that class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

gcc accepts the following code, while clang rejects it.

```
struct S
{
    struct Type
    {
    };
    operator Type()
    {
        return Type();
    }
};
void f(S& s)
{
    s.operator Type(); // error: unknown type name 'Type'
}
```

The standard says `Type` is "looked up in the class of the object expression" `S`. It seems gcc includes the members of `S` in the search, while clang <strike>considers only `S` and its base classes</strike> doesn't. Which is correct?

Relevant quote from C++ Working Draft N3337:

> #### 3.4.5 Class member access [basic.lookup.classref]/7
>
> If the id-expression is a conversion-function-id, its conversion-type-id is **first looked up in the class of the
> object expression** and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire
> postfix-expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case gcc is right. The lookup rule dictates that lookup for `Type` should be performed first in the context of the type of the object then in the context of where the expression is used. The standard even provides an example, that although not exact is similar to yours:

```
struct A { };
namespace N {
  struct A {
    void g() { }
    template <class T> operator T();
  };
}
int main() {
   N::A a;
   a.operator A(); // calls N::A::operator N::A
}
```

Lookup starts inside `::N::A` where it finds the injected name `A` and resolves it to be `::N::A`.

Comment: I found the standard's example to be inconclusive, because it only requires that the name `A` be found within `A`. clang actually gets that one right, but fails with my example.

Comment: @willj: The example clearly states that lookup starts in the class `::N::A`, and the wording is also clear: *first looked up **in** the class of the object expression*. Now if what you want is some rationalization for the behavior of clang (or VS 2010 for what matters) this is not it

Comment: @willj: BTW, clang++ 3.2 calls the wrong conversion function for the example above, it calls `::N::A::operator ::A()`, you can verify that by using the result with this template: `template <typename T> void print_type(T);` (do not define the function). The compiler will process the code and make the decision as of what it wants to do, then the linker will complain that `void print_type<A>(A)` is undefined. If you direct lookup, by calling `print_type(a.operator ::N::A())`, then the linker error will point at the expected type according to the standard.

Comment: my mistake - I thought I'd tested that example with clang. Your analysis agrees with my interpretation of the standard.